# How to hide an Overlay with tap somewhere on the Screen with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wrote a `Widget` that contains a `Button`. On tap on this `Button`, a small "box" is shown with some text information inside.
I solved this with an `Overlay`. Inside of this `Overlay` is a `GestureDetector`. When you tap on the `Overlay` the `Overlay` will be hidden.
Because the `Overlay` is not filling the whole screen it will not be closed if you tap behind this `Overlay`.
But I want that the `Overlay` will be hidden when you tap somewhere on the screen, maybe outside of the `Overlay`.

Here is the part of the Overlay:

```
class _OverlayHelpWidgetState extends State<OverlayHelpWidget> {
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  OverlayState _overlayState;
  bool _isVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.help,
              color: Colors.green[800],
            ),
            onTap: () {
              showHelp();
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    );
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: _createContent(),
          onTap: () {
            hideHelp();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showHelp() async {
    if (!_isVisible) {
      _overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
      _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
      _overlayState.insert(_overlayEntry);
      _isVisible = true;
    }
  }

  void hideHelp() {
    _isVisible = false;
    _overlayEntry.remove();
  }
```

Can someone help me to solve it?

thanks, Bhuelse

Comment: `GestureDetector > Align >_createContent()` maybe? also play with `GestureDetector.behavior` property

Comment: You can add a Boolean variable indicating whether or not the box is showing and in the `on tap` method of `Row`->`GestureDetector` check that Boolean and execute the appropriate method (showHelp/HideHelp)

Answer (score 12):

Thanks pskink,

thats the solution. Changed to this and it works:

```
  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: _createContent(),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          hideHelp();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: without `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` it did not work (but with the same hierarchy: detector>align>content)?

Comment: Without the behavior, it changes nothing. With the behavior, it works correct.

Comment: ok thanks, but actually i am wondering if  original align>detector>content would work too (but of course with `HitTestBehavior.translucent`)... can you check it just for testing?

Comment: align>detector>content didn't work, with and without behavior.